How to use an ArrayPool outside of a simple loop scenario
I pull live images from a camera in a tight loop and use them to update a live WPF image on the display.  In memory profiling I saw that my simple approach was hammering the large-object pool hard.
while (IsLive)
{
    var size = camera.GetParamInt(PRM.IMAGE_PAYLOAD_SIZE);  // Determine size needed
    var data = new byte[size];                              // Getbuffer
    camera.GetImage(data);                                  // Get image.
    ImageReceivedEvent?.Invoke(this, data);                 // Tell clients of new image
}

So I used ArrayPool.Shared minimize the GC hit like this:
while (IsLive)
{
    var size = camera.GetParamInt(PRM.IMAGE_PAYLOAD_SIZE);  // Determine size needed
    var data = ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Rent(size);           // Rent buffer
    camera.GetImage(data);                                  // Get image.
    ImageReceivedEvent?.Invoke(this, data);                 // Tell clients of new image
    ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Return(data);                    // Done with buffer
}

But this approach requires that clients can only use the image data for the immediate duration of the ImageReceived event.  Because I need to return the buffer at the end of my loop.
Now my app has new requirements to do one or several post-processing steps which read these images.  One step might search the image data for some recognizable feature.  Another might check the lens focus.  Another might try to extract a QR code.
These steps do not happen every frame but often enough.  They must be done asynchronously and sometimes simultaneously when there is more than one step.
So I can no longer just call ArrayPool.Return in the loop because I don't know when clients are going to be done with my big buffer of image data. I don't even know the order in which they'll use it.  Yet I want to avoid forcing clients to make copies of these big images as that will just hit the large-object heap even more.
What I want, basically is to be able to Rent the buffer, hand it off to clients and be sure that Return be called when the last client is done with it.   It's almost as if I need the C# equivalent of C++'s std::shared_ptr.  But that is not an approach that seems do-able (or desirable) in a garbage-collected language.
Is there an approach I can take to achieve this, or am I just stuck with operator new[] and large-object-heap thrashing?

You can also pass a disposable object to your users that returns the array on disposing.

Is the asynchronous usage of the buffer infrequent enough that consumers of the data can copy it to long term storage whenever they'll need it for longer than the duration of the event handler?  Does it need to be the responsibility of this code to manage that?

@GyörgyKőszeg  I would do that, but unfortunately since there are multiple "users" (i.e.  multiple post-processing steps in  indeterminate order) None of those would know definitively if it should Dispose of the object.  They certainly would not want to Dispose of it before the other operations were done.

@Servy, I suppose I could make it part of the protocol that clients copy the data if they must.  That would simply move the GC thrashing problem down the line but I could also strongly suggest that they copy it to a similarly allocated buffer (i.e. their own buffer from ArrayPool<>).  I'll do that if I must but it sure would be nice to find an easier way.  Other developers don't always follow the suggested protocol out of sheer laziness.  And if they fail to copy the data at all, then we're in for a world of hard-to-track-down bugs

You can implement the fundamental strategy of a shared pointer in C# by just having an integer that you increment when a new "owner" is created and decrement as each one goes away.
While you can't make this as easy to implement as C++, nor can you ensure it's not possible to "leak" the reference, you can leverage IDisposable to make it not terribly difficult.
public class RentedArray<T> : IDisposable
{
    public T[] Array { get; private set; }
    private int activeReferences = 1;

    public RentedArray(int minimumLength)
    {
        Array = ArrayPool<T>.Shared.Rent(minimumLength);
    }

    public static implicit operator T[](RentedArray<T> rentedArray)
    {
        return rentedArray.Array;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        activeReferences--;
        if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref activeReferences) <= 0)
            ArrayPool<T>.Shared.Return(Array);
    }

    public IDisposable KeepAlive()
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref activeReferences);
        return this;
    }
}

With that you can fire the event by using that type instead of an array:
while (IsLive)
{
    var size = camera.GetParamInt(PRM.IMAGE_PAYLOAD_SIZE);  // Determine size needed
    using var data = new RentedArray<byte>(size);           // Rent buffer
    camera.GetImage(data);                                  // Get image.
    ImageReceivedEvent?.Invoke(this, data);                 // Tell clients of new image
}

And from there any synchronous consumers can just use the array, and asynchronous consumers just need to know to call KeepAlive:
public void ConsumeEventSynchronously(object sender, RentedArray<byte> data)
{
    Console.WriteLine(data.Array.Length);
}
public async void ConsumeEventAsynchronously(object sender, RentedArray<byte> data)
{
    using (data.KeepAlive())
    {
        await Task.Delay(500);
        Console.WriteLine(data.Array.Length);
    }
}


That looks like exactly what I'm looking for.  I am going to give this a shot and report back.

There is nothing build-in AFAIK. You can roll out some helper class to incapsulate this or similar logic. The simplest one can look like the following (relying on the fact that you own the code you should know how many processes you have):
class BufferHolder<T>
{
    public T[] Array { get; }
    private readonly ArrayPool<T> _pool;
    private int _count;

    public BufferHolder(ArrayPool<T> pool, T[] array, int count)
    {
        _pool = pool;
        Array = array;
        _count = count;
    }

    public void Release()
    {
        var val = Interlocked.Decrement(ref _count);
        if (val < 0)
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }

        if (val == 0)
        {
            _pool.Return(Array);
        }
    }
}

Which can be improved by wrapping into disposable (though arguably it is a bit non-idiomatic approach here) and moving "registration" to clients (i.e. using Interlocked.Increment for client to register that it is using the array instead of manually providing the count)
And then consuming code will call Release when the processing is finished.
Another approach would be to save data to some storage and read it to the rented array in every consumer.
P.S.
Note that ArrayPool will just create a new array on Rent if it is out of free arrays (see the GC.AllocateUninitializedArray call in the Rent implemetation for the shared one, or ConfigurableArrayPool.Rent), so be sure that used pool is big enough.
